# spawn_monitor() and 'DOWN' messages

Tags: erlang

Is it (theoretically) possible that the process that's been `spawn_monitor()`'ed exits (with the normal exit or on error) without sending `'DOWN'` message to the parent process ? I have a very strange process leakage, it seems like some of the processes do not send `'DOWN'` message. I am using Erlang package that comes with Ubuntu 9.10. Maybe it is a known bug ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to show some code.  Monitoring is pretty core to the way erlang works.

It's hard to tell what your actual problem is since you're not describing what you're seeing, so I'll have to guess.

You're either not trying to receive the down message or the process isn't exiting.

If you have processes *leaking*, it sounds like they're not actually exiting.

You very well may be trying to build your own `supervisor` module.  I'd strongly suggest using OTP's supervisor if you want sane process tree shutdown and/or restart.

Comment: I agree with Dustin. It sounds like your processes aren't exiting at all (specially when you say you have a process leak).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you *demonitored* the process at some point?

Reading from the doc for erlang:demonitor/1:

> Once erlang:demonitor(MonitorRef) has returned it is guaranteed that no
>   {'DOWN', MonitorRef, _, _, _} message
>   due to the monitor will be placed in
>   the callers message queue in the
>   future. A {'DOWN', MonitorRef, _, _,
>   _} message might have been placed in the callers message queue prior to the
>   call, though. Therefore, in most
>   cases, it is advisable to remove such
>   a 'DOWN' message from the message
>   queue after monitoring has been
>   stopped. erlang:demonitor(MonitorRef,
>   [flush]) can be used instead of
>   erlang:demonitor(MonitorRef) if this
>   cleanup is wanted.

Comment: I don't understand why do I need to demonitor() process when it already died ?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to demonitor it. I'm just wondering if you used that function. Sorry about the confusion...

Comment: I've just replaced "did" with "maybe" :)

Comment: No, I did not use this function(). Most certainly it is a bug somewhere in the logic of my program, but I just want to be sure there are no known issues of that sort in Erlang itself.